# How did Majapahit 14th century timepieces tell the time?

Tags: ancient-history, cultural-history, indonesia, 14th-century, indochina

The Majapahit Kingdom existed from 1293-1527. In that period, international trade was already being done. I'm looking at the cultural history and customs from Majapahit Kingdom, and I was wondering if the Majapahit already implemented clocks like in Europe in the 14th century. However, I seem to find mostly trade between the Majapahit and the Tiongkok. So I want to know if there is an idea about what object(s) they used to show time. Perhaps you can also tell me about the units of they used to show time, such as, minutes, hours, or something similar?

Comment: [Sundials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial) and [hourglasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hourglass). What else would you expect? Maybe also candles.

Comment: I can't find any evidence to suggest they had any such objects, and only vague hints that they might have divided the day into hours for divination purposes.